# Java Custom Tree Model updating problem

Tags: java, swing, tree, treemodel

Here is structure of the tree:

root
-branches
--leafs

I use for TreeModel DefaultTreeModel and my objects implement TreeNode interface

leaf is some Object:

```
public class Leaf implements TreeNode
{
   // implementation
```

branch has List of leafs:

```
public class Branch implements TreeNode
{
 private List<Leaf> leafs;

 // implementation
```

And root is container of branches:

```
public class Root implements TreeNode
{
  private List<Branch> branches;

  // implementation
```

When I add new leaf, my tree doesn't updated, when I add leaf and create new DefaultTreeModel with my root object it's updated. I watch DefaultMutableTreeNode implementation, there isn't any event firing on inserting childs... What am I doing wrong? Before, I tried to implement TreeModel interface wich looks much better then implementing TreeNode interface for three classes, but result was similar. I also read about GlazedLists, but I dislike their tree conception. For me, the best is implementation TreeModel interface conception, but how to update model when some inner List in model add new element?...

Comment: there is great method DefaultTreeModel.reload(TreeNode node) :) it solve problem.

Comment: no, that doesn't solve the error in your code - it only hacks around it.

Comment: So, TreeNode implementations are wrong? They must fire some events?

Comment: no, typically nodes dont fire (they dont know enough) - the code which does the modification must notify the model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the code, it's hard to be sure - nevertheless I'll bet on my guess: you don't notify the TreeModel about your insertions ;-)

A code snippet of what you have to do if your node implementation is not of type MutableTreeNode:

```
 // do the parent wiring in your custom TreeNode
 int position = myBranch.addChild(node);
 // notify the model 
 model.nodesWhereInserted(myBranch, new int[] {pos});
```

If it is of type MutableTreeNode, the easier way is via the convenience methods in DefaultTreeModel

```
 model.insertNodeInto(node, myBranch, position)
```

Comment: thanks, it's what I looking for, now I found how it's implemented in DefaultTreeModel

Answer (score 2):

that look like as issue with [Concurrency in Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), maybe updates are out of EDT,

you have add new Object, then to test `DefaultTreeModel` if contains new Object, if Objects exists, then you have to wrap (all updates) into `invokeLater`, for `Serializable` or `Observate` would be better look for `invokeAndWait`

Comment: bet that's not the issue here :-)

Comment: somebody has (and we talking about Friday) still unbelievable magic globe, lady, lady my +1